# Appropriate life cycle method in which to adjust a layout parameter

Tags: android

Say I only want to adjust the width of a view to match the screen width, but want to maintain any other params defined statically in the XML. I get the params of the view, set the width, then set the params back.

```
private void setWidth(RecyclerView rv) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
       rv.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    rv.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Is it okay for me to set the width in `onCreate()` or is there a more appropriate life cycle method, like for instance, where the view has been instantiated, but not drawn on the screen yet?

**edit**

From what I understand, `onCreate` is the correct method, since there is no earlier life cycle method, and the UI has not yet been drawn in onCreate. Is that correct?